# Does Cloud DNS have a peering limit?

Tags: google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-networking

I am peering many [Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas) instances to a central hub.  Is there a limit on the number of peering connections I can make?  I do not see any mention of this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's no limit per se, but the limit is way higher than your VPC Peerings, so is improbable that you will hit your DNS peering limit before your VPC Peering limit.

With that said, in 2 years I haven't reached that limit.

Comment: vpc peering is not required for dns peering in google cloud , so hitting dns peering limit is independent of hitting vpc limit .. however, yeah it is very high .. unlikely to hit normally